# Unable to register pytest helper functions

Tags: python, pytest

Unable to register pytest helper functions. It keeps failing with the following error.

```
sh-4.2$ python
Python 3.6.11 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Aug  5 2020, 20:09:42) 
[GCC 7.5.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> pytest_plugins = ['helpers_namespace']
>>> 
>>> import pytest
>>> 
>>> @pytest.helpers.register
... def foo(bar):
...     '''
...     this dumb helper function will just return what you pass to it
...     '''
...     return bar
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'pytest' has no attribute 'helpers'
```

- pytest-helpers-namespace~=2019.1.8
- pytest~=5.4.3

Comment: Did you put the code into `conftest.py`?

Comment: This will not work from the interactive shell, you need to start a test run by actually invoking `pytest` in order for module patching to succeed.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. It worked as soon as I put it in a `conftest.py`